# The backspace escape \b in elixir isn't working

Tags: elixir, escaping

### The backspace escape

> From my experience in C

```
iex> IO.puts("Hello Wor\bld\b!")
```

should actually return

```
"Hello Wol!"
```

With this it means that the `\b` actually backspaced the character that came before it. 
So I tried to do this same thing in elixir and got a different output with the same.
The output is as follows
[Output as per my entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHXbf.png)

`"Hello World!"`

This happens the same in escaping for a new line. `\n`
Please help.. Trying to solve a kata here.
Other characters that escape are as follows

```
\a BEL (0x07) 
\b BS (0x08)
\d DEL (0x7f)
\e ESC (0x1b) 
\f FF (0x0c)
\n NL (0x0a)
\r CR (0x0d) 
\s SP (0x20)
\t TAB (0x09)
\v VT (0x0b) \
\uhhh 1–6 hex digits 
\xhh 2 hex digits
```

Comment: One solution would be to use regex, but I'm more interested in finding out why it doesn't work [when it should](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html#interpolation-and-escaping-in-sigils).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erlang console `erl`, `iex`, is built on the top of, plays dirty tricks with the standard input and output.

Use `:stderr` to print your string, it’s untouched by `erl` driver:

```
iex|1 ▶ IO.puts(:stderr, "Hello Wor\bld\b!")
Hello Wol!
```

If you have the code in the file/project that is run with `mix` or directly as `elixir my_file.ex` everything will obviously work for any standard output.

Comment: Interesting that it works with `stderr` as expected but not `stdout`

Comment: I kinda explained why.